# How to pass data to newly added array element components

Tags: reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

How to pass additional data to newly added array element components by onAddClick props?
onAddClick: (event) => void: A function that adds a new item to the array.

[docs](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-customization/#array-field-template)

I just need to copy item and create new one with data of clicked one.

This is how I remove an item

```
const handleRemove = () => {
if (typeof formContext.removeObject === 'function') {
  formContext.removeObject(index, props.onDropIndexClick(index), title);
} else {
  props.onDropIndexClick(index)();
}
```

};

This is how I render them

```
export function CardArray(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { title, items, canAdd, onAddClick, formContext } = props;

  return (
    <Card className={classes.wrapper}>
      <CollapseTitle title={title}>
        {items.map(element => arrayItem(element, formContext, classes, 
         title))}           
      </CollapseTitle>
      {canAdd && (
        <CardActions>
          <Fab
            className={classes.addObjButton}
            color="primary"
            size="small"
            onClick={onAddClick}
          >
            <AddIcon />
          </Fab>
        </CardActions>
      )}
    </Card>
   ); 
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  What things have you tried?  You'll get better results if you follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `updater` function when modifying states:

```
const onAddClick = () => {
 this.setState(prevState => ({
  items: [...prevState.items, newItem]
 }))
}
```

you could als us `concat` cuz it returns a new array:

```
const onAddClick = () => {
  this.setState({ 
   items: this.state.items.concat([newItem])
  })
}
```

or if you are familiar with `ES6` (which I think you do) then you can use the `Spread Operator`:

```
const onAddClick = () => {
  this.setState({
   arrayvar: [...this.state.arrayvar, newelement]
  })
}
```